# C# AS2 Protocol

Tags: c#, http, сеть, x509certificate, signature

C# хочу написать as2 over http, и такой вопрос.

Если смотреть на то как он работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То видно что  нужно сделать DIGEST, вопрос это digital signature? Если да, то я не понимаю что происходит)

Вопрос, я повинен подписать с помощю своего private key документ до отсылки?
А потом сделать Encrypt с помощю public key(сертификата).

Теперь вопрос допустим я это сделал ) И я тепер получатель сообщения.

Ко мне пришло сообщение, допустим я делаю DECRYPT, а потом каким образом сделать VERIFY? если я не знаю текст сообщение, а знаю его digital signature? ну типа у меня захешированые сообщение)

Типа я не понимаю как проиходит DIGEST, SIGN <-> VERIFY, DIGEST

типа нужно в http (body) подать хеш и отдельно текст?
или как это работает ) я запутался) помогите пж)

Comment: Поищите готовые библиотеки. Из их кода можно получить все ответы.